# GMAIL SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I am sending emails using Gmail SMTP in PHP. I also enabled OPENSSL in php.ini. But I am getting this error.

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond. (10060)
>  The following From address
>   failed: mhtkumar46@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected
>   Send mail fail.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require("PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->From = "mhtkumar46@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Mohit";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // specif smtp server
$mail->SMTPSecure= "tls"; // Used instead of TLS when only POP mail is selected
$mail->Port = 587; // Used instead of 587 when only POP mail is selected
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "mhtkumar46@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "*******"; // SMTP password
$mail->AddAddress("mohitkumarsingla60@gmail.com", "Singla"); //replace myname and mypassword to yours
$mail->AddReplyTo("mhtkumar46@gmail.com", "Mohit");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:\\temp\\js-bak.sql"); // add attachments
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/11-10-00.zip");

$mail->IsHTML(true); // set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'test';
$mail->Body = 'test';

if($mail->Send()) {echo "Send mail successfully";}
else {echo "Send mail fail";} 
?>
```

I am unable to find the solution. Please help me.

Comment: Is from email correct?

Comment: After enabling OPENSSL. Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: yes. I restarted Apache.

Comment: May be port problem. Have you tried with some other port numbers. `$mail->Port = 587;`

Comment: Yes. Tried. But Error is same.

Comment: Gmail - SSL/TLS encrypted SMTP uses port 465

Comment: I tried with port 465. but no benefits.

Comment: With the same error???

Comment: You have debugging on, whats in the log?

Comment: Where can I find the log?

Comment: Well you start by looking at the manual

Comment: Anyone here.. solve my problem please..